# Como unificar ramas de un repositorio remoto

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

quería saber como puedo unificar ramas de un repositorio remoto.

Hice una aplicación para saber el clima y al querer subirla, en el repositorio remoto se creó la base en la rama main (eso por GitHub).
Después agregué el resto del proyecto y hice el commit y push por GitBash.

[image: twoBranches]

Cuando veo el repositorio, veo que me pusheó todo en una rama "master", y he buscado por varios lugares e intentado formas durante horas pero no las he podido fusionar, quisiera saber como hacer o por lo menos alguna idea así lo resuelvo.
Quiero dejar todo en la rama main. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Usa el comando git merge

Comment: haces un git pull te bajas la main y despues un merge en main llamando a master lo comiteas y subes con git push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si las ramas quedaron sin un ancestto común, dado que es un proyecto nuevo, yo montaría lo que hiciste en `master` sobre `main` (que es la rama que tiene el repositorio remoto). Asumiendo que es origin:

```
git checkout main
git pull # traer los últimos cambios a main local
git rebase --onto main --root master
# ahora tu master debe estar montada sobre main en una línea recta
# si es así:
git branch -f main # poner main aquí
git push origin main
```

Y listo.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, gracias !

Comment: @CristianEmanuelCamposFuente Si esta respuesta fue útil (No necesariamente tiene que ser la respuesta, solo ser útil), el protocolo es hacer _upvote_ (hacer click en la flecha hacia arriba que está a la izquierda de la resopuesta). Si esta es **la** respuesta, entonces se hace click sobre el _check_ que está debajo de las flechas.

Comment: No sabía, gracias! Ahí le dí como  _check_

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia que es que todo lo dejes en "main", pero si de verdad te importan los nombres, haz esto:

1. `git switch -c main`, para cambiarnos a la rama local "main"
2. `git pull origin main`, para bajar los cambios de la raman "main" remota, pero a tu repositorio local. **Aquí puedes tener conflictos y los deberás resolver antes de hacer commit**
3. `git switch master`, y nos volvemos a la rama local "master"
4. `git rebase -i main`, y con esto, **desde master**, podemos aplicar interactivamente los commits hechos en master y main. También podemos mezclar o renombrar commits. "p" o "pick", le indican a git que aplique los commits; "s", o "squash", que aplique el commit pero que lo mezcle con el commit de arriba (sólo al primer commit no se le puede aplicar el squash). Pero dejándolo todo como esta en el archivo, y cerrándolo, debería quedar
5. Cerramos el editor
6. (Opcional) En caso de que haya conflictos, resolverlos y darles `git add` a los archivos, y continuar con `git rebase --continue`. Si no nos gusta, damos `git rebase --abort` para dejar todo antes del rebase
7. `git push -f origin master`, para que los cambios locales se suban a la rama remota

En resumen, se tiene que hacer que lo remoto sea reflejo de lo que sucedió localmente. Es decir, bajas todos los cambios remotos, operas localmente, y luego todo lo que operaste localmente, lo vuelves remoto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, voy a investigar mas sobre esto, porque en los materiales que enseñan siempre son comandos básicos, esto no vi hasta ahora. Gracias!

Comment: @CristianEmanuelCamposFuente, si te funcionaron o te fueron de ayuda las respuestas y explicaciones, puntúalas o márcalas como las que solucionaron tu problema. De esta manera más personas con tu problema sabrán que estas respuestas fueron de ayuda.

Comment: La puntué pero por mi reputación no figura como publico. Igual me sirvió mucho la ayuda !